# Tkinter label size not matching

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a Human machine interface design...
I have created an array of labels...I have used same label and properties for all the labels in the array, but when i executive my code, size of the labels do not match with each other....

This is my code....

```
from tkinter import *    
import time

root = Tk()

class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time1 = ''
        self.time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        self.mFrame = Frame()
        self.mFrame.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

        self.bottomFrame = Frame()
        self.bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=BOTH)

        root.title('HUMAN MACHINE INTERFACE')

        self.company_name=Label(self.mFrame, text='Host Company Name', font=('Arial',24,'bold','underline'),bg='white',relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)

        self.machine_name=Label(self.mFrame, text='Machine name', font=('Arial',24,'bold','underline'),bg='yellow',relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)

        self.my_company_name=Label(self.mFrame, text='SYNERGY AUTOMATION', font=('Arial',24,'bold','underline'),relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=LEFT)

        self.watch = Label(self.mFrame, text=self.time2, font=('times',24,'bold'),relief=SUNKEN)
        self.watch.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.clock() #first call it manually

        num=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16',]
        r=0
        c=0

        for i in num:
            Label(self.bottomFrame, text=i,bg='red',fg='white',font=(34),padx=50,pady=20,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=r,column=c)
            c = c + 1
            if c == 4 or c == 8:
                c=0
                r=r+1




    def clock(self): 
        self.time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        self.watch.configure(text=self.time2)
        self.mFrame.after(200, self.clock) #it'll call itself continuously

obj1 = Clock()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using the `sticky` option when you call `grid`. Without it, the labels will only be big enough to contain the text. If you want them to fill the table cells, use something like `sticky=N+S+E+W`

```
Label(...).grid(... sticky=N+S+E+W)
```

By the way,

```
self.company_name=Label(...).pack(fill=X)
```

You are setting `self.company_name` to `None` because that's what `pack` returns. A tkinter best practice is to separate the creation of the widget from laying it out on the screen:

```
self.company_name=Label(...)
...
self.company_name.pack(fill=X)
```